# How to create non-exclusive checkboxes with the same name in an Acrobat/PDF form

Tags: pdf, acrobat

In Acrobat Professional, I create multiple checkboxes and assign the same *name* to each checkbox, but a different *export value*. With this, the checkboxes seem to behave like radio buttons: Acrobat only lets me check one of them. If the first is checked, and I click on the second one, Acrobat unchecks the first one.

If I assign different names to the checkboxes, then they do behave independently. However it would make things easier for my code that fills out the form if the name could be the same. Is it possible to create non-exclusive checkboxes (i.e. real checkboxes) that have the same name in Acrobat?

(For reference, this is the PDF I created: [20110503-exclusive-checkboxes.pdf](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6900/resources/20110503-exclusive-checkboxes.pdf))

[image: Same name, different export value]

Comment: your question is probably not related to programming.

Comment: @Bobrovsky, yes, you're right: I am pushing the envelope here ;). But since I need this in the context of some code that manipulates PDF files, I hope that some other programmers will also find this useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from the PDF Reference, it's impossible to create independent checkboxes with the same name.

In fact, a PDF Viewer should use the name to detect which checkboxes will form a *check box field*.

See Adobe's [PDF Reference](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference16.pdf), 8.6.3 Field Types, Check Boxes (page 648) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Use the same name and export value for all your checkboxes and they will checked/unchecked together. Adobe Acrobat supports this, it is also permitted by PDF specification.

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done.

That is the *very definition* of how you define radio groups in a PDF.

You can have different check boxes "foo.MyCheck", "bar.MyCheck", and so forth, and all are different fields.  Different parent fields can have children with the same local name but different fully qualified names.  Not a problem.

What is it that you're trying to do, anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Acrobat versions 8,9 and X allow you to create non-exclusive checkboxes. Although, this allows you to create non-exclusive checkboxes, Orbeon does not recognize these fields.

Once you create the initial checkbox,

**Right click the check box and select "Place Multiple Fields..."**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASj3Q.png

**In the Create Multiple Dialog box modify the number of fields needed (down/accross)** 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYOoU.png

**Then select the other checkbox properties to modify the Export Values**